# Getting undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass when trying to access database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have this line in the route:

```
get 'applications', to: 'admin#applications'
```

Have this in the admin controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
def applications
  @students = Student.all
end
```

Inside applications.html.erb, this is the line of error:

```
<% @students.each do |student| %>
```

From some basic print debugging, it seems that the function applications is never executed in the admin controller and the HTML file is not rendered successfully.

Note: I don't have any issues like this inside the Student controller and views.

Comment: Make sure there is no typo in instance variable name `@students`. Share you rails console log.

Comment: Hi. "it seems that the function applications is never executed in the admin controller" - why do you think so? Please share error messages